# List comprehension structure in Python

Tags: python

I have the following structure

```
list1 = ["ab","ac","cd","de","fh","abcc","abcdef"]
list2 = ["acebfh"]
comprehension = [item for item in list1
                 if list(list2).count(i) < list(item).count(i) 
                 for i in set(list2)]
```

but returns:

> i is referenced before assignment

Is there a way to do this with list comprehension ?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: For good style, list comprehensions are best used for simple loops. Use a regular for loop for more complex loops and tests.

Comment: The answer to your questions is "yes" and there are a few more thorough answers below, but the confusion you're experiencing here is a good example of why complicated list comprehensions are best avoided.

Comment: The test is meaningless, as it will always be `False`. `set(list2)` is just set with one item in it, so `i = "acebfh"`. `list(list2)` just recreates `list2` which has `i` in it, so `list(list2).count(i) == 1` but `list(item).count(i)` will be `0` for every `item`. What do you expect `list(list2)` and `list(list1)` to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehensions are written in the same order as their nested full-specified counterparts, so lets unpack this.  What you wrote essentially translates to:

```
for item in list1:
    if list(list2).count(i) < list(item).count(i):
        for i in set(list2):
            list.append(item)
```

Notice that we are referencing i in the if statement before it's defined in the for loop.

If what you want is the equivalent of this:

```
for item in list1:
    for i in set(list2):
        if list(list2).count(i) < list(item).count(i):
            list.append(item)
```

then you could write your list comprehension as:

```
comprehension = [item for item in list1
                 for i in set(list2)
                 if list(list2).count(i) < list(item).count(i)]
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension for nested loops is the opposite of what you might expect. You're trying to do something like

```
[i for i in range(j) for j in range(10)]
```

whereas you should be doing something like

```
[i for j in range(10) for i in range(j)]
```

In other words, the "inner" loop comes after the outer one, whereas you have the the inner loop (and condition) coming first.